# How to convert dynamic value to type value in expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression

```
public class Model1 {
    public String Value { get; set; }

}
public class Model2 {
    public dynamic Value { get; set; }
}

public static Expression<Func<Model2, Model1>> GetExpression() {
    return f => new Model1 {
        Value = f.Value
    };
}
```

I am writing a `GetExpression()` which convert `Model2` property to `Model1`. When it comes to dynamic property, I try `Convert.ToString(f.Value)` or `(String)f.Value` but it said

> "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation"

Anyone know what is the proper way to convert dynamic value to type value in expression?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I'm curious why all the downvotes on this question? Aside from the premise being odd, it's a valid question.

Comment: @DavidG I agree. I suspect that downvoters did not fully understand the question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Phew, I thought I was missing something obvious for a while!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this is to convince the expression compiler to overlook the `dynamic`:

```
return f => new Model1
{
    Value = (string)(object)f.Value
};
```

or

```
return f => new Model1
{
    Value = Convert.ToString((object)f.Value)
};
```

With anything else, there is going to be an implicit dynamic conversion, which isn't supported. This just does a hard cast instead.

However, frankly I wonder whether there's much value in `f.Value` *being `dynamic` in the first place*.

Answer (score 3):

You can move the code that builds `Model1` from `Model2` into a method, and use that method in your expression, like this:

```
private static Model1 FromMolde2(Model2 m2) {
    return new Model1 { Value = m2.Value };
}
public static Expression<Func<Model2, Model1>> GetExpression() {
    return f => FromMolde2(f);
}
```

One side benefit of this approach is that the code that copies properties from `Model2` into `Model1` is available for reuse.

Another possibility is to give `Model1` an additional constructor that takes `Model2`, but this would introduce a potentially undesirable dependency between the two classes.